# Can Ethernet interleave multiple packets at the same time on the same link?

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Can Ethernet interleave multiple packets at the same time on the same link ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "interleave" but I update Windows and update Kali at the same instant in time. Ethernet sort out the packets by the requests it got.

Comment: Packages or packets?

Comment: Ethernet doesn't have packets. It has frames.

Answer (score 3):

If by "interleaved" you mean that packets from different applications can be sent out in any order, then yes. A program can begin sending packets and if another program sends a packet during the same time then it could conceivably be sent in-between the other packets.

You could easily have a packet order of

1. Packet from program 1
2. Packet from program 2
3. Packet from program 1
4. Packet from program 1

But each packet would have to be sent in its entirety before the next one is sent.

Remember that each packet of data has individual "to" and "from" data that can be used to route them all individually.

If you mean can two packets be smeared together and sent at the same time, then the answer is no.

A packet itself cannot be broken down. There would be no easy way to disentangle which bits were from either packet on the line.

Comment: "There would be no easy way to disentangle which bits were from either packet on the line" – some other link types do interleave packets that way, e.g. ADSL and (I think) SDH, it works as long as the bits are interleaved in a fixed pattern (e.g. 1/2/3/4/1/2/3/4/..) and not just put in a blender.

Comment: Indeed, but that would usually be handled by special multiplexer and demultiplexer hardware, and would be more convenient in electronics that is more complex in its use of a spectrum of frequencies for transmission (as ADSL does). ADSL tries to spread a data across a broad range of frequencies in order to avoid using one single very high speed signal. Ethernet expects a better quality and shorter link so drives at a pure binary on/off which is faster and simpler to implement, ADSL expects a dubious link of limited bandwidth and makes more efficient use of the available connection.

Answer (score 2):

No, whole Ethernet packets are not interleaved – at least for "regular" twisted-pair or fiber Ethernet, as far as I know, each frame must be serialized in full before another can begin.

(Although 1G and faster Ethernet connections do consist of multiple independent "lanes", the data is split across lanes only *after* it has been serialized, i.e. they are used to simultaneously send multiple bits from the same byte (or something like that) – not multiple frames at once.)

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet can't interleave a single packet across other packets, but IP can.  If the IP packet is too large for ethernet, it can be fragmented into multiple ethernet packets, and this separation would allow interleaving.

The core design of both ethernet and IP is that everything is packet based, and every host on the network can send packets.  Part of the design includes timing that prevents a single host from dominating the network entirely, all hosts get an opportunity to send packets between other hosts packets.  (Although this could be limited by congestion.)